# iwspy does not work

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I'm using my Raspberry Pi to **measure the signal strength** of `WIFI` devices. I have tried with **iwspy** command but it shows me

> error as follows

```
wlan0 Inteface doesn't support wireless statics collection.
```

Comment: please post your `lsusb -v` output - and I'll be able to help you further =)

Comment: No all wlan adapters implement or expose the API for "collection" - You have to try another one or find one that others suggest. Intel based usually do it all, and many realtek and ralink.

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin I have a very long result I give you an ewample of Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424: 9514 Standard Microsystems Corps.
Coudn't open device, some information will be missing
Device descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorTupe 1
bcdUSB 2.00
bDescriptorClass 9 Hub
bDevicreSubClass 0 Unused
bDeviceProtocol 2 TT per port

Comment: @CyrineNasri try to use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for long results - it's a *proper* way to give a full details

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Interface doesn't support wireless statics collection... Maybe another wifi device does support this.

Otherwise I think I'll have to disappoint you, [Google](http://bfy.tw/4Czw) told me mac80211 support has been phased out in the tool you are using. [Link here.](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=51e779f0daa5c712439d37b907d58543e4fcf12a)

you could try `iwconfig`, this reports QOL and signal strength.